# How to pause or stop the sprite kit game when the user enters the background or receives a call

Tags: sprite-kit

When a user enter the background (double taps home button ) or receives a call the game carries on in the background . Hence the score increases while they carry on with the game.I need to know how to pause or stop the game when they enter the background or receive a call . My app is in swift 3 , Xcode 8 .

Answer (score 2):

Like John said, you need to pause the game.. but to do so, you need a reference to the gamescene instance / object. Here is a static reference that you can use in your AppDelegate:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  static var sharedInstance = GameScene()

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    sharedInstance = self
  }
}
```

Then, in the AppDelegate functions, you can use:

```
GameScene.sharedInstance.isPaused = true // or false
```

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate.swift, Xcode puts a method by default called `applicationWillResignActive`. This is what you should see unless you edited or removed the method:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // ...
}
```

From Xcode's template...

> Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive
>   state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions
>   (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits
>   the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
>   Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate
>   graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause
>   the game.

Since this method is called just before the game becomes inactive, my suggestion would be to use this method to recognize that your game has been paused. You can place whatever code you need in this method to actually pause specific tasks of your game.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should pause the game in [applicationWillResignActive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive):

> You should use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and
>   throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to
>   pause the game. An app in the inactive state should do minimal work
>   while it waits to transition to either the active or background state.

At the moment of speaking (eariler this wasn't a case), when you return from background, eg. return to active state, the scene will be unpaused automatically. Sometimes this is desired behaviour, sometimes it is not.

For example, sometimes you want your game to stay paused when user returns from a background. In this case, you will fire a notification from appropriate AppDelegate's method. Then you will catch this notification in GameScene and take needed actions (eg. pause the game again, or pause a world node, and show popup over it to let the user continue when he wants...)

Pausing going automatically too. When you go to background, the scene is paused. You don't really have to do anything if you just want your scene to stay paused.